# OSX won't automatically connect to WiFi

Tags: macos, wifi

About a week ago, my OSX machine stopped connecting to any WiFi networks automatically. If I open the WiFi menu from the top bar and select the desired network, it connects OK. Also, if I enable "Ask to join new networks" from the Network preferences, it shows the "No preferred networks found" dialog, even though the network is both in the list shown in that window AND in the preferred networks list in Network preferences -> WiFi -> Advanced...`.

The issue is repeatable both in my work and home networks. As far as I know, I've done no configuration changes or updates or such since the 10.8.3 update.

UPDATE: This may be hackintosh-related, since I get an error message from the bootloader saying `Unable to handle key preferred-networks`. I'm not sure what this site's stance on hackintoshes is so I posted this on the bootloader's forum as well.
UPDATE 2: Not an issue of the bootloader.

Edit: In reference to Buscar's comment, this is my view of the network preferences:

[image]

Comment: If you check the Automatically Join this network it does not work ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Where can I find that option?

Comment: Network, right under the network name above the ask to join

Comment: @Buscar웃 There is no such option, see updated question.

Comment: in os x 10.8.3 MBA

Comment: OSX 10.8.3 MBP/Hackintosh

Comment: do you know how to reset your wifi settings (in plist)

Comment: Before we get to serious with Terminal commands,  just try to update your Airport utility to version 6.2

Comment: Airport utility already was at version 6.2, I tried removing `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist` and `NetworkInterfaces.plist` from `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`, no change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading this question reminded me that I had dealt with the same problem with my Mac awhile ago.

I fixed it by writing a shell script which was automatically called via `launchd` whenever `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/` changes.

You'll have to configure a few things, mainly create a list of known SSIDs and passwords for the networks that you join.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/tjluoma/airport-autojoin

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad to hear it was useful to someone else, especially after I re-wrote it :-)  If you pull it apart and try some of the commands on the command-line, you might get a better error message than what System Preferences shows you.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes network locations get messed up, but you can start fresh: go into the Location menu and create a new network location. Click on Apply, and check again and the WiFi situation improves.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't change the situation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the Advanced button on the Network Preference page.
2. On the next page, select the checkbox on the "Remember networks this computer has join".